# ayuda form para subir titulo, imagenes y links con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario que debe de enviar título, dos imagenes y varios links, mi problema no es enviar nada de esas cosas, el punto es cuando quiero que todo se envie en un solo form no logro hacer el php correcto, las imagenes se suben pero se suben en diferentes ID de las bases de datos en vez de subirse todo junto, aqui les dejo el codigo php:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$j = 1;
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"][$i] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
$parte1="";
$parte1.= "http://demo.com";
$parte1.= substr($target_file, 2);


// Inserta el nuevo usuario a la base de datos.  
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO articulos (imagen$j) VALUES (?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $parte1);
            // Ejecuta la consulta preparada.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
$j = $j + 1;
} else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}
header('Location: ../añadir.php');
```

Comment: ese codigo php es solo para subir las dos imagenes, arreglando eso planeo agregar la insercion del titulo y los links

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de como aparecen los datos en la BD?

Comment: si estan de esta forma: id  |titulo |imagen1 |imagen2 |categoria |HD |Opcion1 |Opcion2 |Opcion3   los demas campos planeo ponerlos despues de solucionar el inconveniente de las imagenes, ahorita lo que quiero es que las dos imagenes se pongan en el mismo id no en separados

Comment: y al subir las dos imagenes me aparecen asi 1  NULL
http://demo.com/uploads/cloud_public.png
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: y 2
NULL
http://demo.com/uploads/cloud_private.pn...
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: Creo que sería más fácil que edites la pregunta y pongas toda esa información ahí. Gracias.

Comment: estoy desarrollando algo parecido, pero me parece que lo mejor es crear una carpeta con el id (un unico id) y dentro de ello meter todos los documentos que quieras, no solo fotos... es decir, subir los archivos, no añadirlos a la base de datos...

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo que estas poniendo en efecto como te indicant solo es el `insert` para la imagen, no para los demas datos, en algun momento hice algo parecido a lo que quieres, te compartire el codigo que yo use, espero te funcione de algo o al menos para aclarar tu duda

```
<?php session_start();

require 'config.php';
require '../functions.php';

comprobarSession();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: ../error.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $titulo = limpiarDatos($_POST['titulo']);
    $extracto = limpiarDatos($_POST['extracto']);
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
    $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'];

    $archivo_subido = '../' . $blog_config['carpeta_imagenes'] . $_FILES['thumb']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($thumb, $archivo_subido);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO articulos (id, titulo, extracto, texto, thumb)
    VALUES (null, :titulo, :extracto, :texto, :thumb)'
    );

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':titulo' => $titulo,
        ':extracto' => $extracto,
        ':texto' => $texto,
        ':thumb' => $_FILES['thumb']['name']
    ));

    header('Location: '. RUTA . '/admin');
}

require '../views/nuevo.view.php';

?>
```